# Async redux action to fetch data is causing component to reload and cause react to react max depth in reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create a component that allows detecting changes in the redux store. Once the shouldUpdateData flag is set in the store, the component responsible for updating should fetch the data by using an async action creator. In my case, either the error "Maximum updates have reached" occurs or the update never happens.

Depending on the dispatch function stopFetching() (turns off the shouldUpdateData flag), the error or outcome changes. If I do the dispatch inside the action creator there are endless updates. If the code is used as it is below, no update occurs.

The reason I used the useSelector() hook from 'react-redux' is to detect a change in the store for the loading attribute.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the action creator:

```js
export function updateDataAsync(id) {
    return function (dispatch) {

        // dispatch(fetchDataRequest());

        return fetch(`/api/user/${id}/data`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                let {projects, notes} = result;
                // New data and dispatch function
                dispatch(fetchDataSuccess({projects, notes}));
            },
            (error) => { dispatch(fetchDataFailure(error)) }
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the reducer for this action creator:

```js
export function savedData(state = DATA_INITIAL_STATE, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_STATES.FETCH_DATA_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case FETCH_STATES.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: action.data,
                error: ''
            }
        case FETCH_STATES.FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: {},
                error: action.error.message
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The React component that is doing the update:

```js
function StoreUpdater({ update, userId, shouldUpdate, startFetch, stopFetch, children }) {

    const loading = useSelector(state => state.savedData.loading);
    let reqSent = useRef(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!reqSent && shouldUpdate) {
            startFetch();
            update(userId)
            reqSent.context = true;
        }
    })

    return loading ? <LoadingAnimation /> : children;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userId: state.user.id,
        shouldUpdate: state.shouldUpdateData      // The flag that should trigger the update
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        stopFetch: () => { dispatch(setShouldFetchData(false)) },
        update: (id) => { dispatch(updateDataAsync(id)) },
        startFetch: () => dispatch(fetchDataRequest()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoreUpdater);
```

Comment: The `useEffect` has no dependency array, so it will trigger on every render cycle. Is this intended use case? When do you want it called?

Comment: @DrewReese no it was not intended. Thank you changed it. Now it is loading once but the data is not received from the store.

Comment: May just need to add some subset of `reqSent`, `shouldUpdate`, `startFetch`, and `update` to the dependency array so it triggers when any of them change/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference I created inside the component responsible of the updates, was causing the problem. The reference was preventing the update dispatch to occur due to the if statement being false.

Answer (score 1):

You dint pass any dependency to `useEffect` so it will be called on every `render` which is causing infinite renders

change `useEffect` to

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    if(!reqSent && shouldUpdate) {
        startFetch();
        update(userId)
        reqSent.context = true;
    }
},[])
```

For complete information regarding `useEffect` refer [this](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) link

Answer (score 1):

`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` were `react-redux` higher order functions to `connect` **classes** components into the store. there equalants at functional components are `useSelector` and `useDispatch`. re-write your HOC redux adaption into hooks, and add [ dependency ] at `useEffect` usage

---

```
function StoreUpdater({ update, userId, shouldUpdate, startFetch, stopFetch, children }) {

 const loading = useSelector(state => state.savedData.loading);
 const userId = useSelector(state => state.user.id);
 const shouldUpdate = useSelector(state => state.shouldUpdateData);
 let reqSent = useRef(false);
 const dispatch = useDispatch() // import from 'react-redux'

 useEffect(()=>{
    if(!reqSent && shouldUpdate) {
        dispatch(startFetch());
        dispatch(update(userId));
        reqSent.context = true;
    }
 }, [reqSent, shouldUpdate, startFetch, dispatch, update, userId]) 

 return loading ? <LoadingAnimation /> : children;
}

export default StoreUpdater ;
```

Comment: There is really no need to rewrite/convert these to the hook equivalents, the values from redux state would still be the same. The `connect` HOC works for ***any*** react component. All you've really done is added and defined the hook dependencies. I'll not downvote this answer but it really isn't helpful.